# Handle Null Value

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am sending data from jsp through ajax call to controller, while it is object data(not a simple String), so sometimes it may be not initialize before sending, so I may be get **null or "null" or undefined**.

So in controller I need to compare in the following way

```
if(request.getParameter("variableName")!=null && !request.getParameter("variableName").equals("null") && !request.getParameter("variableName").equals("undefined"))
```

It looks too dirty, which is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Save `request.getParameter("variableName")` to a String before the `if` statement.

Comment: I have not issue with that, I don't want to compare variable with null or "null" or "undefined", So I am asking about alternative for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step it to avoid duplicated action, sow you should assign the result to a variable.

`String result = request.getParameter("variableName");`

Then instead of locking the logic in some if, you could check that application should continue.

```
if(result == null || "null".equals(result) || "undefined".equals(result)) {

   return; //or throw if required

}
```

As you probably will validate that very often you could extract the code to class RequestUtils, that could have static method validateRequestParameter(request, "variableName"), that will return true if valid else false.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call, before submitting the request ensure you send non-null value or empty string if null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code as below.

```
Object obj = request.getParameter("variableName");
if(obj != null && !obj.equals("null") && !obj.equals("undefined"))
```

But the better option is to handle it just before sending the data via ajax to controller.